# Calling an Async Function from Mounted Hook in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm attempting to call an API which fetches me data from my mounted hook, but nothing is being triggered. I'm assuming its due to it being an asynchronous function, but my knowledge is thin on this in regards to the mounted hook. How would I go about ensuring this works, is a mounted hook perhaps not the right place to call it?

Code:

```
export default {
  name: 'Input',
  mixins: [BaseInput],

  mounted() {
    this.getBookingData();
  },

  methods : {
    getBookingData() {

    (async () => {
      let data;

      function status() {
        const url = `/files/id/entries`;
        return axios.get(url).then((resp) => {
          return resp.data;
    })
      }
      data = await status();
      console.log(data)
    })
  }},
```

Comment: for me it's not clear what you intend to do.
you are returning a promise from a function inside another function, but you don't handle it's result

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just your method that's a bit quirky. Maybe try this:

```
methods: {
    async getBookingData() {
        const url = `/files/id/entries`;
        const { data } = axios.get(url);
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```